# MySQL Subquery in Conditional Statement

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, conditional-statements

I've got a small problem with sub-queries as conditions.

This is the code I'm trying to figure out:

```
  SELECT `page`  
  FROM `mdl_tool_devcourse` 
  WHERE `page` IN
            (SELECT `objectid` 
            FROM `mdl_logstore_standard_log` 
            WHERE `action` = 'viewed' AND `objecttable` = 'wiki_pages' AND `userid` = 2)

            AND `ref` IN

            (SELECT `objectid` 
            FROM `mdl_logstore_standard_log` 
            WHERE `action` = 'viewed' AND `objecttable` = 'wiki_pages' AND `userid` = 2)
```

So in my WHERE statement I want both `page` and `ref` to be among the results from my subquery. To achieve this I couldn't find any other way than to run the subquery twice. Is there another option to have the subquery executed only once?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  This looks like an unusual data model.

Answer (score 1):

Subqueries are ultra slow. Try to run that query:

```
SELECT
    `mdl_tool_devcourse`.`page`
FROM `mdl_tool_devcourse`
INNER JOIN `mdl_logstore_standard_log` ON `mdl_logstore_standard_log`.`action` = 'viewed'
    AND `mdl_logstore_standard_log`.`objecttable` = 'wiki_pages'
    AND `mdl_logstore_standard_log`.`userid` = 2
    AND `mdl_tool_devcourse`.`page` = `mdl_logstore_standard_log`.`objectid`
    AND `mdl_tool_devcourse`.`page` = `mdl_logstore_standard_log`.`ref`
```